# How to add UIBarbuttonItem at centre on UInavigationbar in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationbar

I only add UIBarbuttonitem at left or right. Now i want to add UIbarbuttonitem at centre on uinavigationbar. How can i do that? Thanks much

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
 UIButton *titleButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
 [titleButton setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 170, 35)];
 self.navigationItem.titleView =  [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:titleButton];
```

Answer (score 1):

You could add another UIBarButtonItem as a 'spacer' like this:

```
UIBarButtonItem *barButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Button" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:@selector(buttonTapped)];
UIBarButtonItem *spacer = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFixedSpace target:nil action:nil];
spacer.width = 125.0f;

[self.navigationItem setRightBarButtonItems:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:spacer, barButton, nil]];
```

Comment: UIBarButtonSystemItemFixedSpace will not center when rotate.  How to fix?

Comment: Yeah, I think @AbdullahShafique's answer is the way to go, honestly. Because getting the width of a `UIBarButtonItem` for proper spacing is too complicated.